# UI for variable input by user in R

Tags: r, user-interface

I have  a sequence of variables numerical and boolean that I want a user to input when running the script. The variables `x`, `y` and `z` are defined with default values:

```
x = 25
y = 1.2
z = TRUE
```

And the variables are used in the script.

Is there a package with a function to show one dialogue box and input `x`, `y` and `z` then continue running the code.

I attempted with `svDialogs` however, I am getting one input per dialogue box.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: does it have to be GUI? or (since u say u r running a script) wouldn't console input be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, a GUI is needed - I basically need it for a user who never seen r/rstudio to just hit run.

Comment: But you are never gonna be able to avoid running it in some Console (be it R console or CMD or BASH), isn't it like that?

Comment: @GWD hmm... I guess I am talking specifically for rstudio, where a user opens a code.R file and hits the run button. While the file is actually run in R console, the user is not interacting with it.

Comment: What’s wrong with Shiny?

Comment: I have als had good experience with parameterized Rmarkdown reports with those types of use-cases - where they are R newbies but at least able to open the RStudio editor.

Comment: @Limey I am looking at Shiny now, it seems a lot more involved for a simple input dialogue. Do you have an example I can look at?

Comment: @RonakShah has given you an example of how simple a Shiny app can be.  I have nothing to add to his answer, other than to say that you can embed Shiny apps in markdown documents and generate markdown from Shiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to build something simple and basic you don't need `shiny` but if your application is going to grow big with lot of user interaction it is worth learning it.

See this simple example -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput('x', 'Enter value for x :', 25),
  numericInput('y', 'Enter value for y :', 1.25),
  selectInput('z', 'Select value for z :', c(TRUE, FALSE)),
  verbatimTextOutput('result')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$result <- renderText({
    #Perform calculations here
    sprintf('Values selected for x is %.2f, y is %.2f and z is %s', 
            input$x, input$y, input$z)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice: I will be sticking with Shiny. One question on this example, will this write variables x, y, z into R data?

Comment: Never mind. I can do global variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So if console input (by the user) would be sufficient you could try something along these lines:

```
x.input <- readline("Please provide x (just hit ENTER to keep default: ")
if (x.input != "" && is.numeric(x.input)) x <- x.input
```

Repeat and rinse for the other two ... (for z with `... && is.logical(z.input)` - bear in mind that `NA` is also `logical` (in case you need to check for that as potential input as well) and your code should just keep rolling from there.
On top of it you could check for a function exit by the user ...

```
x.input <- readline("Please provide x (press ENTER to keep default or X to exit): ")
if (x.input != "" && is.numeric(x.input)) x <- x.input 
if (x.input == "X") return("Function exit by user!")
```

I have done something similar with some R noob colleagues and usually it was sufficient to explain it to them [once] or to make them aware of needing to just read the console messages when/after they hit run.